# If $f$ is the pdf of a random variable, show that $g(x, y) = f(x+y)/(x + y)$ is a density function in the plane.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f$ be the pdf of a positive random variable and write

$$g(x, y) = \frac{f(x + y)}{x + y} , \text{ if } x, y  > 0.$$

Show that $g$ is the density function in the plane.

---

Clearly, $g(x, y) \geq 0$, but I need help evaluating the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x + y)}{x + y} \mathop{dx dy}. $$

One substitution that looks pretty clear is $u = x + y$. Then, we get the $f(u)$ term, and I know $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(u) \mathop{du} = 1$, but I don't know when I would utilize that.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right direction, but recall that change of variables in dimension 2 requires one more variable $v = v(x,y)$ as well as $u = x+y$. One of the simplest choice is $v=y$. Then, $$du = dx+dy,$$ 
$$dv = dy,$$ and hence
$$dudv = dxdy.
$$ Also, the support of the integral is mapped to $x=u-v>0, y=v>0$. Therefore, the integral has value
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}dxdy =\iint_{0<v<u} \frac{f(u)}{u}dudv = \int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^u \frac{f(u)}{u}dv\right)du = \int_0^\infty f(u)du =1.
$$
$\textbf{Note:}$ A jacobian matrix is involved in the calculation. What $du = dx+dy, ,dv=dy $ means is exactly
$$\left( {\begin{array}{c}
  du \\
   dv\\
  \end{array} } \right) =
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)\left( {\begin{array}{c}
   dx \\
   dy  \\
  \end{array} } \right),
$$ and $\frac{dudv}{dxdy} = 1$ is a jacobian determinant.

Comment: don't we need to do a jacobian ?